# Json$Default cannot be cast to kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

Tags: android, kotlinx.serialization

Problem with kotlinx.serialization and running test in androidTest.

Lib version:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
```

My instance of Json:

```
Json(Json.Default) {
    serializersModule = SerializersModule {
        // serializers here
    }
    coerceInputValues = true
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    isLenient = true
}
```

UI test scheme

stub json -> json deserialise with kotlinx.serialization.json -> show screen

If I run UI test in androidTest folder, I will get exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlinx.serialization.json.Json$Default cannot be cast to kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
```

**Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?**

UPD

Another variant. Use without default

```
Json {
    serializersModule = SerializersModule {
        // serializers here
    }
    coerceInputValues = true
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    isLenient = true
}
```

Exception

```
No static method Json$default(Lkotlinx/serialization/json/Json;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;ILjava/lang/Object;)Lkotlinx/serialization/json/Json
```

Comment: Adding demo project on github would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with allure framework

1. issue here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-kotlin/issues/38
2. fix here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-kotlin/pull/37